# WPF- RadComboBox selected item

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik

I'm using `RadComboBox` in my application and i couldn't able to set the selected item in the control, (i.e) when i click the `dropdown` the list is slided down and when i click on any item it doesn't get set in the `ComboBox`.

//XAML:

```
<telerik:RadRibbonComboBox Name="cmbReports">
    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Content="Report 1" />
    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Content="Report 2" />
    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Content="Report 3" />                                
</telerik:RadRibbonComboBox>
```

Tried adding the static values as `ComboBoxItem` but it also does the same.

Where i'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the object directly, like I do with the strings:

```
<telerik:RadRibbonWindow x:Class="Sample.MainWindow"
                     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                     xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
                     xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                     Title="MainWindow"
                     WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
                     WindowState="Maximized">

<telerik:RadRibbonComboBox Name="cmbReports" Width="200" Height="20">
    <system:String>Report1</system:String>
    <system:String>Report2</system:String>
    <system:String>Report3</system:String>
</telerik:RadRibbonComboBox>
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks. But y doesn't the regular thing doesnt work?

Comment: Because you're adding a RadComboBoxItem inside a RadRibbonComboBox. You're supposed to add a RadRibbonComboBoxItem to make it work the way you expect.

Comment: Thank you. That's the mistake.